# Replacing Setting Flyout with Flyout in Universal App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am developing a Windows 10 universal application.
I had developed application keeping in mind desktop, so I have used "SettingFlyout" for showing settings. But when I try it on Windows Phone 10, it does not show. I researched that we can not use it in Windows Phone and we should use flyout. Is there any easy substitue for SettingFlyout for Windows 10 Phone?
I dont see how Flyout can replace SettingFlyout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SpliView` ? A lots of apps using it for setting placement: e.g: Mail and Outlook.

Comment: i am using split view, one side i have spit view content and setting  has to come from other side

Comment: Use another `SpliView` with empty content, and put your Setting in Pane, set placement of the Pane to the other side.